# Android Parse JSON Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

How Can I parse a JSON ARRAY to get the data without the [] and ""

here is the json

```
"formattedAddress": [
"23, Damansara - Puchong Hwy (Bandar Puchong Jaya)",
"47100 Puchong Batu Dua Belas, Selangor",
"Malaysia"
]
```

my code:

```
poi.setFormattedAddress(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getJSONArray("formattedAddress").toString());
```

output:
[ "23, Damansara - Puchong Hwy (Bandar Puchong Jaya)",  "47100 Puchong Batu Dua Belas, Selangor",  "Malaysia" ]

I just want the data. as:

23, Damansara - Puchong Hwy (Bandar Puchong Jaya), 47100 Puchong Batu Dua Belas, Selangor, Malaysia

Thanks

Comment: may be your JSon array is not correct. please check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: Yeah I think your json is not correct....

Comment: try reading the data as an array of Strings.   String[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSONArray#join()` to join the elements. Check out the [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#join(java.lang.String)) docs for more info.

```
poi.setFormattedAddress(
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location")
       .getJSONArray("formattedAddress").join(", ")); // passing ", " as the separator
```

It's unclear if the quotations are part of your input JSON string. If they show up in your join, you can easily remove them with the `String#replace()` method.

```
System.out.println(jsonArray.join(", ").replace("\"", ""));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried .join and this is the output: "Northpoint Midvalley City", "Kuala Lumpur, Kuala Lumpur", "Malaysia"

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the .join(", ").replace("\"", ""));  - it now works

Comment: Please, refresh the page so that my edits show up. Use replace() as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public String getFormattedAddressFromArray(JSONArray array) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        strings.add(array.getString(i));
      }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return TextUtils.join(", ", strings);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONArray.join():

```
getJSONArray("formattedAddress").join(","));
```